# Generic React/Typescript function has function in props but does not detect return type when param added

Tags: typescript, function, object, return-type, derived-types

Guys I have no idea what title to put for this question, but here is my problem: I'm trying to add typescript restrictions nested many levels deep for react components and contexts.

I've distilled my roadblock to this miniature code sample:

```
function simplified<T>(props: { generator: () => T, receiver: (t: T) => any }) {
}

function whatIWant<T>(props: { generator: (bob: any) => T, receiver: (t: T) => any }) {
}

function nonObject<T>(generator: (bob: any) => T, receiver: (t: T) => any) {
}

simplified({ generator: () => 123, receiver: (t) => console.log(t + 2) })
whatIWant({ generator: (bob) => bob ? 1 : 2, receiver: (t) => console.log(t + 2) })
nonObject((bob) => bob ? 1 : 2, (t) => console.log(t + 2))
```

The `whatIWant` function is showing an error because it thinks `t` is `unknown` type.

The other two (`simplified` and `nonObject` are correctly seeing `t` as a `number` type.

In the end, `generator` will be returning an object with several keys and types and I want those to be automatic. I do not want to add `<>` type params when invoking `whatIWant`. I've noticed they are not required for `simplified`. Any ideas?

[image]

I'm particularly confused by the difference between `simplified` and `whatIWant`

TypeScript 4.5.4

Comment: Posted bug report: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48279